# Java rest WS to download docx

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, docx

I´m developing a Springboot rest-based web app. One of the WS must return a .docx document. The code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-doc",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<File> getDoc() {
    File file = userService.getDocx();
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DocxProject.docx");
    header.setContentLength(file.length());

    return new HttpEntity<File>(file,header);
}
```

but I´m facing this error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

I searched other questions but none of them gave me a solution, mainly because they use javax.ws.rs but I don't want to rely on it.

What I´m looking for is a solution to the error I get or an alternative to my code (not javax.ws.rs dependant).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's filtering header Content-type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try returning array of bytes. Simplifying your code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-doc",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getDoc() {
    File file = userService.getDocx();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] doc = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
    return doc;
}
```

**IOUtils** is from `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`. I have not tested, but I have a similar method that return an image. I hope this help you.

Comment: You pointed me to the solution. I changed mi "File" to "byte[]" and used IOUtils like you said but I kept HttpEntity and now it´s working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the stream directly in response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-doc",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getDoc(HttpServletResponse response){
     InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
     ..
     response.flushBuffer();
}
```